# Splitting GeoJSON column, what is in one dictionary?

Tags: qgis, geojson

I'm new to GIS. I can't find anything to solve my problem.
What instrument can I use to do this? (pandas, geopandas)

[image]

Comment: what is the original file type (and source if possible)? you can do this easily with pandas

Comment: original format is geojson, I didn't found how to do this, can you explain it, please?

Comment: Please provide more details: what field type does the `Attributes` field have (string/text?). Would be using QGIS expression an acceptable solution? If you could provide some sample data, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the very rudimentary information you provided, you can try something like this, using QGIS expressions with `map`. Please provide more information for a an answer more to the point - but the basics should become clear from the following example and you can use it where you need it:

To get the **fieldnames** as an array, use `map_akeys`:

```
map_akeys( 
    json_to_map( 
        '{"UNOM": 10044, "OBJ_TYPE":"Zdanie","OnTerritoryOfMoscow":"da","ADDRESS":"gorod moskva, ulica Kiprenskogo, dom 4"}'
    )
)
```

Output looks something like: `[ 'ADDRESS', 'OBJ_TYPE', 'OnTerritoryOfMoscow', 'UNOM' ]`

With array_first (), you get: `'ADDRESS'`. Use `array_get(array,index)` to get each element of the array.

---

To get the **attribute-values** as an array, use `map_avals`:

```
map_avals( 
    json_to_map( 
    '{"UNOM": 10044, "OBJ_TYPE":"Zdanie","OnTerritoryOfMoscow":"da","ADDRESS":"gorod moskva, ulica Kiprenskogo, dom 4"}'
    )
)
```

Output looks something like: `[ 'gorod moskva, ulica Kiprenskogo, dom 4', 'Zdanie', 'da'… ]`

With array_first (), you get: `'gorod moskva, ulica Kiprenskogo, dom 4'`. Use `array_get(array,index)` to get each element of the array.